# Authenticating REST calls (/nifi-api) with an OIDC-secured NiFi instance

Tags: apache-nifi

Has anyone been able to make progress on successfully authenticating via REST calls (/nifi-api) with an OIDC-secured NiFi instance? I've scoured the interwebs and see a lot of old posts asking about it, but no updated info.

I have NiFi configured such that we can successfully authenticate via the UI with a redirect to Azure Active Directory. However, we need to now start building a custom application that can edit flows on users’ behalf, and thus our application needs to communicate directly with NiFi APIs. I’ve played around with creating a new Service Principal in Azure and getting a bearer token for that service principal, which is in the same tenant that my OIDC setup is configured to, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to trade that valid (from AAD’s perspective) Bearer token for a JWT from NiFi. Is there any programmatic way of interacting with the /access/oidc/exchange endpoint?

I can reach into the browser and copy the JWT from an authenticated browser session with the NiFi UI and execute REST calls with /nifi-api that way and it works, but that's obviously not a valid flow here. We need something that doesn't rely on browser redirects.

Comment: Is using OIDC/per user authentication for the application required? Can you use a service user X509 client cert to authenticate with the API and make the requests on the users behalf?

Comment: Sounds like this question to oidc flow you are using to authenticate application.

Answer (score 0):

NiFi does not support this feature yet. Please refer to the Jira issue here. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-11014

I managed to access NiFi APIs from java program using X.509 authentication. Below are the steps.

1. NiFi 1.15.3 is secured with Keycloak using OIDC protocol.
2. composite-file-user-group provider configured at authorizers.xml file.

```
<userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>file-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">CN=api_client, OU=**, O=**, ST=**, C=**</property>
</userGroupProvider>
```

```
<userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>composite-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.CompositeUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider 1">file-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="User Group Provider 2">ldap-user-group-provider</property>
</userGroupProvider>
```

```
<accessPolicyProvider>
        <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">composite-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">***</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
        <property name="Node Group"></property>
        <property name="NiFi Identity 1">CN=api_client, OU=dastc, O=**, L=**, ST=**, C=**</property>
</accessPolicyProvider>
```

3. I have generated a client certificate and provided NiFi Identity property.CN=api_client, OU=***, O=****, L=***, ST=***, C=**
4. Started NiFi server
5. Logged-in to NiFi UI as initial admin and granted all global access policies and component level access policies to Flow
6. Developed a Java program to using mutual ssl handshake (Send client certificates as SSL context) and now I can invoke NiFi APIs.
7. Test authentication API

```
curl https://****:9443/nifi-api/access --insecure --cacert root-ca.pem --key api_client.key --cert api_client.cert.pem

Response: {"accessStatus":{"identity":"CN=api_client, OU=**, O=**, L=**, ST=**, C=**","status":"ACTIVE","message":"Access Granted: Certificate authenticated."}}
```